# WEBKIT: javascript function defined within if (0) called

Tags: function, google-chrome, webkit, redefinition

Using a function which is first checked whether it is already defined gives issues under any Webkit browser.
Sometimes I use a function from js module A and in another application I want to use the same function with the same name (but slightly different code) from module B.
I solve this by the typeof operator to check whether it is "undefined".
The following example (for clarity all in one file) shows what I do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript function definition test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

// actually in module A.js
function foo()
{
  alert("This is the first function.");
}

// actually in module B.js

if (typeof(foo)=="undefined") {
function foo()
{
  alert("This is the second function when foo() is undefined.");
}

}
// This definition SHOULD be ignored in all cases but Webkit does run this despite the if (false) !!

if (false) {
function foo()
{
  alert("This is the third function when foo() is defined within if (false).");
}

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
foo();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I discovered that in Chrome (android and OSX), Boat Browser (Android), Safari (OSX) ALWAYS the last defined function is called despite it is disabled between if (false) condition.
When one removes this, the second definition between typeof "undefined" is called despite the function is defined earlier.

Under Firefox (OSX, Android) it calls correctly the first function.

Is this a bug in the Webkit engine or am I overlooking something ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a fluke that it worked in some browsers, and it didn't work for the reason you think.

Function definitions are "hoisted", so that the function is available when it is in scope, not where it is defined.

For example, this is legal

```
a();
function a() {
}
```

since in evaluation, the function definition is hoisted to the top and becomes

```
function a() {
}
a();
```

Instead, do this:

```
if(window.foo === undefined) {
    window.foo = function() {
        alert("This is the second function when foo() is undefined.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Paul Draper's reply, function definitions are hoisted to the top of the scope.

Your problem can be fixed by declaring your functions like this:

```
var foo;

foo = function ()
{
  alert("This is the first function.");
}

// actually in module B.js

if (typeof(foo)=="undefined") {
  foo = function ()
  {
    alert("This is the second function when foo() is undefined.");
  }
}
// This definition SHOULD be ignored in all cases but Webkit does run this despite the if (false) !!

if (false) {
  foo = function ()
  {
    alert("This is the third function when foo() is defined within if (false).");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directive function name() means that you are declaring function in window scope. 
You need link your function to certain variable.

```
var myFunc=function(){ alert(1);};
if (true){
  myFunc=function(){alert(2);}
}
if (false){
  myFunc=function(){alert(3);}
}
myFunc();
```

Alert 2 will fire.